# Homotopy colimit construction for internal group actions of $\Omega X$ in spaces over $X$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

Let $\mathbf{CW}$ be the category of based connected CW-complexes. Let $D(\mathbf{CW}/X)$ be the homotopy category of based connected CW-complexes over (based overcategory!) a based connected CW-complex $X$. By *based overcategory* is meant that all of its objects are maps preserving the base, and that the maps involved in the commutative triangles preserve the base as well.

I am interested in the internal group $\Omega X : \operatorname{IntGrp}(D(\mathbf{CW}/X))$ and its internal actions $P : \operatorname{IntGrpAct}(D(\mathbf{CW}/X),ΩX)$.

The homotopy pullback with a point $pY$ of $Y : D(\mathbf{CW}/X)$ can be viewed as an object in $\operatorname{IntGrpAct}(D(\mathbf{CW}/X),\Omega X)$ (i.e. an internal groupoid action of $\Omega X$). (I accidentally said mapping cone at first sorry!)

I had one idea about the construction of a functor $\partial : \operatorname{IntGrpAct}(D(\mathbf{CW}/X),\Omega X) \to D(\mathbf{CW}/X)$ which is isomorphic to $B \Omega X$ in the case of the object $\Omega X$ (its own action), and which in general is constructed via homotopy colimit.

Actually, I think I want to quotient this by an apparent $G$-action to get $\partial$.

Somehow I want this functor $\partial$ to maybe be the geometric realization of a simplicial space? And also I wanted $\partial p$ to behave like $B \Omega$.

My guess is that the simplicial space I want (built from an internal $\Omega X$-action $P$) is built out of a simplicial object $F : \Delta^* \to \mathbf{CW}$ sending $[n]$ to $G^n \times P$, and that the geometric realization of this simplicial object has a nice relationship with $M$. The simplicial object should feature $\mu : G \times P \rightarrow P$ as one of its degeneracies or faces. After this, the geometric realization has an action of $G$ on it, and we quotient by that.

All in all, I am trying to go based on analogy with the situation for   ΩB and BΩ.

1. Can you construct such a functor which has $\partial p \cong \operatorname{id}_{D(\mathbf{CW}/X)}$ (naturally isomorphic)?
2. Can you construct such a functor which has $p \partial \cong \operatorname{id}_{\large \text{internal } \Omega X \text{-actions}}$?

I fully understand that this is basically the equivalence between $G$-principal bundles and spaces over $BG$ (plus taking $G = \Omega X$). But the focus of my question is **this homotopy colimit construction** - specifically this geometric realization which witnesses the equivalence of categories claimed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle) (at the very beginning).